# Data not getting printed properly

Tags: spring-mvc

I am writing code in spring mvc. It's very basic like taking the data from one jsp page than after writing post method in controller I want to fetch that details in success page but after writing post method I am getting where it should print the details. I am not understanding where I have gone wrong here. I am pasting the code:

dinInForm.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; 
    charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
        prefix="form"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>DineInReservationSystem
    </title>
    <style>
    .error {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Dine In Reservation System</h2>
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="dineInForm" action="save.do">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> Resturant 
    </td>
    <td><form:select path="resturant">
    <form:option value="" label="select resturant"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${resturantList}"></form:options>
    </form:select></td>
    <td><form:errors path="resturant" cssClass="error" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>DIne Type</td>
    <td><form:select path="dineType">
    <form:option value="lake View" label="lake View"/>
    <form:option value="Roof View" label="Roof View"/>
    </form:select>
    <td><form:errors path="dineType" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Date(DD/MM/yyyy)</td>
    <td><form:input path="date"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="date" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>TIme(Lunch/Dinner)</td>
    <td>
    12:00PM<form:radiobutton path="time"/></td>
    <td>01:00PM<form:radiobutton path="time"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    08:00PM<form:radiobutton path="time"/></td>
    <td>09:00PM<form:radiobutton path="time"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="time" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>No. Of Guest</td>
    <td><form:input path="noOfGuest"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="noOfGuest" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Mobile Number</td>
    <td><form:input path="mobNo"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
    </body>
    </html>




    Success.jsp
    ----------------
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <%@ page session="false" %>
        <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>DineInReservationSystem
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Dine-In reservation system</h2>
    <h4>Acknowledgement---------------------------------</h4>
    <h3>Thank you for choosing ${dineInForm.resturant} resturant</h3>
    <h4>Here are your details</h4>
    Customer name : ${name} <br>  `enter code here`
    No of guest : ${dineInForm.noOfGuest} <br>  
    Time: ${dineInForm.time}<br>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/save.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveDineInDetail(@Valid DineInForm dineInForm,
                BindingResult res,Model model)
        {
            if(res.hasErrors())
            {
                return "dinInForm"; 
            }
            model.addAttribute("dineInForm",dineInForm);
             model.addAttribute("name", dineInForm.getName());
            System.out.println(dineInForm.getMobNo());
            return "success";
        }`
```

Getting the output in browser like this

```
    Dine-In reservation system
    Acknowledgement---------------------------------
    Thank you for choosing ${dineInForm.resturant} resturant
    Here are your details
    Customer name : ${name} 
    No of guest : ${dineInForm.noOfGuest} 
    Time: ${dineIn

Form.time}
```

Comment: are you returning "sucess.jsp"?

Comment: Yes I want to return the data in success.jsp page